# jsoup multiline HTML being returned as single line (no break returns)

Tags: android, html, newline, jsoup

I have this HTML I am trying to scrape:

```
    <textarea name="notes" rows="5" cols="60">some notes go here
    and more including a blank line:

    and another new
    line
    etc
    etc
    </textarea>
```

As they are in a textarea there are no brs or \n. I can easily get the full text:

```
    Element notes = doc.select("textarea[name=notes]").first();
    String notesStr = notes.text();
```

But that returned it as a single line while I want to display the result in an editText as follows:

```
    some notes go here
    and more including a blank line:

    and another new
    line
    etc
    etc
```

Comment: What version of JSoup are you using? Tested it with *1.7.2* and my output is with newlines.

Comment: I am using 1.7.2 too! Typical found the problem soon after posting, I am saving all the HTML into a file first...It was being appending without the line returns!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Element notes = doc.select("textarea[name=notes]").first();
String notesStr = notes.getWholeText();
```

getWholeText():Get the (unencoded) text of this text node, including any newlines and spaces present in the original.